# running node to test Json and Ajax, similar to WAMP

Tags: node.js, wamp, web-deployment

This might be a stupid question, but can I setup node.js to run an environment like WAMP? Just to test html docs, JavaScript, Json and Ajax requests.

If this is a good idea or possible, anyone have an advice on setting up the file structure?

Answer (score 1):

You're misunderstanding some Node.js fundamentals. Let's break this down...

### WAMP

#### W - Windows

You can install Node.js on Windows [here](https://nodejs.org/en/download/). Nothing special.

#### A - Apache

While you *can* put Apache in front of node as a load balancer, for development purposes it's likely unnecessary. Node.js doesn't *need* Apache, or nginx. It will happily serve HTTP responses all on its lonesome.

#### M - MySQL

Sure, use MySQL if you want. :) You'll want to install MySQL on your machine, then you can get a driver for it on npm: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql

#### P - PHP

Node.js doesn't run PHP (barring a few most unholy abominations). Try taking a look at [Jade](http://jade-lang.com/).

### The Basics

After you get Node.js installed, I'd recommend taking a look at [Express](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html) and [Jade](http://jade-lang.com/). Start with the Express hello-world. You can run it simply by opening a command line, navigating to the project directory, and running `node hello.js` (or whatever you named the file). Just like that, you'll be serving HTTP requests. No need for a "stack".

Comment: Well put. However it may be handy to include ejs (or similar) in there since the OP may be more comfortable with HTML syntax. Jade is a slight shift and some people find it repulsive, having not used it before.